# How to handle all messages in a group with pyTelegramBotAPI in python

Tags: python, bots, telegram

I am going to build a simple telegram bot that reply with simple message.
But my issue is it is working with command messages like `/start` or `/help`.
What I want to is that it is working with non-commmand messages.
Here is an example.
User: `hello`This is
Bot: `This is a static message`
User: `fine`
Bot: `This is a static message`

Here are my code

```
BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv('BOT_TOKEN')
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Hello. I am a Bot. How are you doing?")


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_all(message):
    initial_message = """
    This is a static message
    """
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, initial_message)


print("bot is running")
bot.infinity_polling()
```

Please let me know how to handle normal messages without starting `/`.
Thanks

Comment: The `@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)` decorator should handle that. I have a telebot project which uses exactly that and it catches all messages. not sure where the error is.

Comment: Thanks, I solved this. We have to add it to admin of the group so that it can answer to any questions